# IIS returns 500 error instead of 404

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application showing custom error pages on my Local and Development test environments without any issue. However, in my Staging environment I'm unable to get custom error pages to show up, I attached the error page that I'm seeing. What is most confusing is that I have custom errors enabled but I always receive a 500 error even when I should be receiving a 404. [image]

Here is what my HTTP Errors section looks like:

```
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/404" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: 500 errors are usually accompanied by an exception, have you attached a debugger or examined the event logs to see if there is an exception being thrown?

Comment: Disable the custom error in your web config and you will be able to see the error

Comment: @CodingGorilla Unfortunately I'm unable to attach a debugger to this as its running on a remote server where I do not have the ability to install Visual Studio to attach to the IIS process. I will have to check the event logs to see what is being logged there.

Comment: @Shyju I've removed the customErrors section entirely from the web.config and this has not made a difference.

Comment: @Matt check out remote debugging: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx.

Comment: Setting httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" also seems to not do anything, I'm still seeing the white error screen.

Comment: Did you solve that issue?